# Application turns off playing music when launched

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

HI i have set my app audio session to ambientsound,
when i launched the app for the fist time she just kill the music.
i dont want this to happen.
there is any other way to set this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

Activate audio session :

```
OSStatus activationResult = NULL;
result = AudioSessionSetActive (true);
```

Test if other audio is playing

```
UInt32 otherAudioIsPlaying;                                   // 1
UInt32 propertySize = sizeof (otherAudioIsPlaying);

AudioSessionGetProperty (                                     // 2
    kAudioSessionProperty_OtherAudioIsPlaying,
    &propertySize,
    &otherAudioIsPlaying
);

if (otherAudioIsPlaying) {                                    // 3
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
                    setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient
                          error: nil];
} else {
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
                    setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient
                          error: nil];
}
```

If YES, allow mixing

```
OSStatus propertySetError = 0;
UInt32 allowMixing = true;
propertySetError = AudioSessionSetProperty (
                       kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers,  // 1
                       sizeof (allowMixing),                                 // 2
                       &allowMixing                                          // 3
                   );
```

Source : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Cookbook/Cookbook.html